# Is there a way to pass login state in separate html files using Firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

I am setting up a website where people can login and then register in courses (Each course is a separate html file).
I want their login state to be saved while navigating

I've already tried using the `onAuthStateChanged()` method but when i move to another course's page from the home page it won't work

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user)
{
    if (user) {
        document.getElementById('joinOurDojo').innerHTML = "Welcome " + user.email +"." ;
        document.getElementById('joinOurDojo').classList.add("w3-allerta");
        document.getElementById('joinOurDojo').classList.add("w3-middle");

        document.getElementById('fbInsta').innerHTML = "Welcome <br>" + user.email + "<br>";
        document.getElementById('fbInsta').classList.add("w3-right");
        document.getElementById('fbInsta').classList.add("w3-allerta");
        document.getElementById('menu_register').innerHTML = "Log out";
        document.getElementById('loginForm_modal').style.display = "none";
        console.log("current user " + user);
    }
```

I connected this `js` file with the home and package course html files
Yet when i move using the login state wouldn't show and the console logs `null`
any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _"it won't work"_?

Comment: _"the console logs `null`"_  this is literally impossible given the code in your question. If `user` is `null`, the code within the `if` block will not execute.

Comment: It wont work as if on the index page i log in but when i try to move from it to another page im not logged in anymore

Comment: @phil i copied the console.log() line to the outside of the if statement

Comment: That's not what you've shown here. Please edit your question to reflect the actual state of your application

Comment: Also, where are you initialising your Firebase app? You have to do that on every page as well